# Efficient storage/querying of word tokens in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dashboard which includes a wordcloud for social media terms used during a certain period of time.

I am currently storing the tokens as a list inside a dataframe in pandas, which would look something like this:

```
Tokens-Columns:
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
['another', 'sentence']
['last', 'sentence']
```

Currently my code iterates through each list building a flat list then counting with a collections.Counter, however, this is really inefficient and when reaching millions of records it's taking ages to process.

Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider limiting your dataset. Stopword removal might be a good way to start, I'm not sure if `a`, `this`, and `the` are particularly useful. Depends on your use-case of course

Comment: Knowing the purpose is critical in designing an efficient data structure and algorithm. What is the goal that you are trying to achieve? If you merely want a word count, simply use a hashmap (dictionary) since it has O(1) operations.

Comment: I already have a cleanup routine, fixing both common typos as well as stopword and punctuation removal during the tokenization process with spaCy. I am thinking in the end the problem comes from making this list of lists hashable